# PHP while statement issues

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops, while-loop

I am having issues with my PHP while statement. It is:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$time_in_12_hour_format = date("g:i a", strtotime($row['Time']));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){  //Creates a loop to loop through results
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Description'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Date'] . " at " . $time_in_12_hour_format . "</td><td>" . $row['Location'] . "</td>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
```

Yes, I do realize I'm defining $row twice, but I'm not sure how to change that. If I remove $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) from the while statement, the page will not load and it returns errors. As of now, the page loads but the table is empty, even though I know for a fact there is one record in there that was displaying in the table before I added my military time converter. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Delete first `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);` and add `$time_in_12_hour_format = date("g:i a", strtotime($row['Time']));` to the cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {  //Creates a loop to loop through results
    $time_in_12_hour_format = date("g:i a", strtotime($row['Time']));
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Description'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Date'] . " at " . $time_in_12_hour_format . "</td><td>" . $row['Location'] . "</td>";  
}
```

Every time you call `mysqli_fetch_array` it fetches a row from table, so since you said your table has one record, the one record will be returned in the first `mysqli_fetch_array` call and eventually the second call to `mysqli_fetch_array` returns `NULL` since there is no more records to fetch in the table

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `$time_in_12_hour_format` into the while loop.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){  //Creates a loop to loop through results
    $time_in_12_hour_format = date("g:i a", strtotime($row['Time']));
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Description'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Date'] . " at " . $time_in_12_hour_format . "</td><td>" . $row['Location'] . "</td>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
}
```

This will also solve defining $row twice, which is what causes the issue in the first place. Because you already called `mysqli_fetch_array($result)` your while loop is starting at row 2.

Answer (score 0):

The `$time_in_12_hour_format` should be set for each row, right? If yes, then try to move it inside the while loop. Your current code will only start to show row 2 and row1 will be ignored. The modified code should look like:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){  //Creates a loop to loop through results
    $time_in_12_hour_format = date("g:i a", strtotime($row['Time']));
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Description'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Date'] . " at " . $time_in_12_hour_format . "</td><td>" . $row['Location'] . "</td>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
}
```